# Can you make multilevel arrays with one query?

Tags: mysql, performance, multi-level

Is it possible to make a multilevel array using a mysql query? E.g. if I want to get 4 pictures for each product?

```
[1] => Array( 'name' => 'Product 1', 'picture' => array('picture1','picture2','picture3','picture4') )
[2] => Array( 'name' => 'Product 2', 'picture' => array('picture5','picture6','picture7','picture8') )
```

Or do I need to make a foreach to loop through the products and then in the foreach make a mysql query to get each products pictures?

EDIT:

My structure is:

```
P_Attributes
--------
id, int(15)
name, varchar(256)


P_AttributeValues
--------
id, int(15)
value, varchar(256)
attribute_id, int(15) [NOTE: This is connected to P_Attributes.id]
```

Then I want to get ALL P_AttributeValues to a P_Attribute row - and get it in ONE query. Is that possible?

EDIT 2:

With the query made by the accepted answers author I made it work with this PHP-code:

```
$attributevalues = $auctionClass->get_rows($id);

$attr_val = array();
foreach($attributevalues as $k => $v){
    $attr_val[$v->AID]['attr_name'] = $v->AName;
    $attr_val[$v->AID]['parameters'][] = array('attr_value_name' => $v->name, 'id' => $v->id);
}
```

Comment: You can pull all the neccessary data in a single query, but you will need to process it in PHP to get the hierarchical structure.

Comment: If you showed the layout of your tables in the database, then example code could be shown.

Comment: Alain: Potato potato... You probably know what I mean.

Comment: Orbling: Would be be unnecessary work to get it all in the query? Or is it better to do a query in a foreach?

Comment: Almost always best to minimise queries and go for a more complex query, once, than lots of little queries.  Providing you have suitable indexes if there are multiple tables joining together.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just use a normal JOIN query and order it, you can get rows coming out of the records that can be formed in to the necessary hierarchical structure.

```
SELECT pa.id AS product_id, pa.name , pav.id AS product_attr_id, pav.value
FROM P_Attributes pa JOIN P_AttributeValues pav ON pav.attribute_id = pa.id
ORDER BY pa.id ASC, pav.id ASC
```

This will generate rows like this:

```
product_id, name, product_attr_id, value
1, "Product 1", 1, "picture1"
1, "Product 1", 2, "picture2"
1, "Product 1", 3, "picture3"
1, "Product 1", 4, "picture4"
2, "Product 2", 5, "picture5"
2, "Product 2", 6, "picture6"
2, "Product 2", 7, "picture7"
2, "Product 2", 8, "picture8"
```

No idea what MySQL extension you are using, presumably PHP as I mentioned it and you didn't correct me.  If you fetch the associative array per record returned, which will be, per record, in this form:

```
array('product_id' => 1, 'name' => "Product 1",
      'product_attr_id' => 1, 'value' => "picture1");
```

If you have a main data array called `$products`, you can produce it by just putting this code in the loop, assuming the record is called `$productRec` and filled in the loop before this.

```
if (!array_key_exists($productRec['product_id'], $products)) {
    $products[$productRec['product_id']] = array('name' => $productRec['name'],
                                                 'picture' => array());
}

$products[$productRec['product_id']]['picture'][$productRec['product_attr_id']] =
    $productRec['value'];
```

Using the IDs for the keys should be alright, presuming that they are primary keys with no duplicates.  Will aid look up that way, rather than losing that data.

Comment: This is actually the way, I did it myself. I ended up with some code, which I share above - I don't check the array_key_exists, because I think it is unnecessary in my situation :-) But thanks a lot!

Comment: @denlau: In your code, the arrays are coming in to being automatically, by uninitialised variables being referenced in array context, hence no need to check, etc.  Not good practice, but it does work.  Glad you've got it working.

Comment: Orbling: I don't understand? :-)

Comment: @denlau: I was just saying that you forgo the `array_key_exists()` call (which is used to initialise the array where it does not exist, as well as the sub-array) and let PHP create the array on the fly when it does not exist, by referencing an unknown variable in array context.  If you had warning mode enabled, it would probably moan at you about that, but it creates the array automatically instead, assuming that was your intention, which on this occasion, it is.  It works your way, just via automatic correction.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good article on doing this type of query:

http://www.xaprb.com/blog/2006/12/07/how-to-select-the-firstleastmax-row-per-group-in-sql/

You might be able to adjust their examples to fit your needs.

Comment: This helped a lot - simple as that. I will try to make this work and check up on the performance :) Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your table structure, you may be able to pull rows that have everything you're looking for, and then code the creation of the array from that row.

Comment: Since you probably have more than one attribute per product, and you've shown us more than one value per attribute, it won't be pretty to get one row back per product.